# Uninstalling Windows

Tags: windows-xp

Would it be safe to uninstall Windows XP on my computer and just boot to Ubuntu? I am using an older computer with a 40 gig HD, 3GB processor and just under 2 GB ram. I do not have much space left on my drive. If can be don

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you should backup your sensitive data before installation.

**Minimal Requirements for Ubuntu Desktop:**

1. 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
2. 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
3. 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
4. VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
5. Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
6. Internet access is helpful

There's also variants of Ubuntu like Lubuntu or Kubuntu which they will run on even weaker PC.

Answer (score 1):

No need to uninstall XP, Ubuntu works OK in dual boot. If you are beginning with linux, dual boot is pretty useful.

For that configuration you can do with a 4 GB swap and a 5 GB as a minimal for the OS.

Also making a backup of your sensitive data before installation is still valid.